# How do I set RSpec to an earlier version?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way to use an earlier version of RSpec without uninstalling the default version? If not, what's the safest way to replace the current version? The uninstall/reinstall instructions linked to in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661261/how-do-i-run-my-specs-with-the-previous-version-of-rspec) seem to be gone.

I'm trying to learn testing with RSpec, and all the tutorials I've found seem to predate 3.0. I invariably get deprecation warnings (if I'm lucky) or errors when using their old expectation syntax. I've relied heavily on [this article](http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/) to set me straight, but the time I spend updating the syntax in the tutorials' examples keeps me from concentrating on the substance of the lessons.

The same SO answer I linked to mentioned a config option in Rails' environment.rb file, but I'm not using Rails for the current tutorial, just Ruby and (eventually) Sinatra. I'm wondering if I can just add that file to be project folder.

I did add a Gemfile with the RSpec 2.1:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rspec', '~> 2.10.0'
gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-rspec'
gem 'terminal-notifier'
gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'
```

The 2.1 installed after running `bundle install`, but after running `bundle exec init` and running my specs with the old syntax, I still get the same deprecation warnings and errors.

Comment: How are you running your specs? `bundle exec rspec spec` should be sufficient. What's the output of `bundle exec rspec --version`?

Comment: Can you please post the links to the tutorials that are not working for you?

Comment: Most issues are due to replacing `should` with `expect` in newer versions. You can tell RSpec to use `should` by setting `expectations.syntax = :should` in spec/spec_helper.rb, which ought to make most older examples work in the current version.

Comment: @Dave: I wasn't familiar with the `bundle exec rspec spec` way to run the specs. That actually worked—I'm not getting deprecation warnings or errors, even without adding the `--version`. Before I was running the specs with just `rspec`.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson: A couple of Tuts+ courses. I'm currently working through [Test-Driven Development in Ruby](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/test-driven-development-in-ruby), and I just finished [OOD in Ruby: SOLID Principles](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/ood-in-ruby-solid-principles), which develops a game project using TDD. A few months ago I did a TDD intro course on Lynda.com, but it used some Java-based NUnit framework.

Comment: @zetetic: I was able to get through one tutorial by applying the `should`/`expect` substitution, but with the current tutorial I've been running into a bunch of edge cases, (e.g. `expect(foo).to receive_message` instead of just `expect(foo).to receive(:bar)`), particularly with mocks and stubs. So far I've been able to eventually find the right syntax, but my priority with the tutorial is learning the basics of testing rather than getting bogged down in debugging specs.

Comment: @Gameboy70 Great! In general you should run everything with `bundle exec`. That runs the executable in the context of the gems from your `Gemfile`, whereas without it just runs whatever was installed on the system. Hence you were getting the older version.

Comment: @Dave: That makes sense. I'm able to get through the tutorial now without updating the syntax, which is fine as a short-term solution. Thanks for the help!